# What does this graph tell about the time complexity?

Tags: c++, sorting, time, graph, time-complexity

--X------Y--
0.035   1000
0.089   2000
0.183   3000
0.315   4000
0.502   5000
0.693   6000
0.925   7000
1.222   8000
1.630   9000
1.998   10000
2.234   11000
2.651   12000
3.096   13000
3.667   14000
4.328   15000
4.865   16000
5.496   17000
6.288   18000
7.037   19000
8.036   20000
19.032  30000
34.167  40000
54.505  50000

Y here corresponds to the no. of random elements taken as input and X is calculated using the function of time in C++ (time.h)

I wish to know , what can you possibly deduce from this graph about the time complexity of my sorting algorithm?

This graph has time(in seconds) on X-Axis and no. of elements on Y-Axix : http://tinypic.com/r/24cz600/8 Please click on the url

Comment: The graph is log-like or sqrt-like. But it would be difficult to say something about the function. You can try a manual fit of the point

Comment: Is there a way to find out the possible function using some technique?

Comment: Plotting N on the x-axis would be more logical, and you'd then see that the chart looks like a power-law. Plotting the points on logarithmic axes would be even better, and would make it straightforward to estimate the power to which N should be raised.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/f50ec6/8 this is how it looks like in Logarithmic axes

Answer (score 5):

Your Big O is almost certainly n^2.  Time should be on the Y axis, as it is a function of `n` operations.

[image]

As you can see in the graph, there is a well defined, almost perfect fit to n^2.

Comment: http://mycurvefit.com/share/f318ddf8-3fb7-40e1-b773-bd7fc9bf87f3 came up with the same numbers.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? Why is it almost certainly n^2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @3ISvZFqczFBVUtz The fit to his data is of the form ax^2 + bx + c, with a very strong correlation coefficient.  When determining Big O, only the largest growth rate matters, which would be x^2.

[This example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example) explains it really well.

Answer (score 1):

It tells that complexity is almost definitely O(N^2) (because it works too long). According to this you can make some suggestions about the sorting algorithm itself - for example this could be the bubble sort.

Comment: <strike>It most definitely is not n^2... the graph is not growing it is going asymptoticalyy to a fixed value (it seems). So it would rather be logX(n)...</strike> I'm a fool who can't read graphs.

Comment: @RedX it is n^2.  Time should be on the Y axis, not the X axis.

Comment: @dwcanillas You are completely right. Sorry for the oversight :(

Comment: @RedX omg, try to be more attentive